# Kendo Scheduler - isDaySlot Error

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, scheduler

In order to use the scheduler for my clients needs, I must lock out certain dates on the scheduler based on certain information from the database. In the schedulers edit event, I use e.preventDefault() if the date clicked isn't able to be edited. This prevents the event modal from popping up successfully. I then click on a date that is able to be edited, so the event modal pops up as expected. I click the "Save" button on the event modal and I get the following error -> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'isDaySlot' of undefined. This javascript error breaks the scheduler until I refresh the page.

Any idea what is causing this issue?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Please show us the code you are using so far.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the issue with latest version of Kendo UI but to no avail - everything is working as expected. That why the issue is most probably **already fixed**.